# Having trouble using takepane.js in an Excel Office Add-in

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js, office-addins

EDIT: Apparently, I misunderstood how Office Add-ins worked. Please see my comment below for how I was able to figure things out.

I was able to get an Excel office add-in working this weekend. The add-in was created with yeoman generator. I'm testing this add-in in both Excel desktop (PC) and Excel online.

The add-in currently runs in the following structure:

1. The add-in contents are uploaded to Github pages
2. The manifest.xml has been updated to replace localhost:3000 with the
   github page site.
3. The manifest.xml has been uploaded to the Integrated Apps page in
   Microsoft 365 Admin Center for my developer account.

In order to get the add-in up and running I had to do a few things:

1. I had to move the files in the taskpane directory (/src/takepane/)
   into the root directory.
2. I had to use a `<script>` tag in the takespane.html file and execute the javascript code there.

If I don't move the taskpane.html file to the root directory, I get a 404 error when I try to load the add-in in Excel Online or Excel desktop once it's been uploaded to Github Pages.

I've tried multiple attempts to reference taskpane.js to get the add-in to reference code in that file. I've tried creating a `<script>` tag referencing this file from takepane.html. And I've looked into changing values in the webpack.config.js and the manifest.xml files. All of my attempts have been unsuccessful.

I was wondering if anyone knew of why I was experiencing these issues. Or could point me in the right direction of what I should be doing. I appreciate any advice. And I'm happy to provide any code requested.

Comment: Do you use any bundler? May be Webpack? Have you tried to use the latest version of  yeoman generator and create a new add-in?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev I just use the standard yeoman generator to create the add-in. I forgot to add that detail. So I'll add that into my post as an edit. I have not tried updating the add-in. I will give it a shot.

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev I updated yeoman and recreated my add-in. I have the new add-in up and running on both Excel desktop and Excel online. However, I ran into the same issue. I needed to put the files from the takepane directory into the root directory. I also think I needed to put the files in the commands directory in the root directory as well.

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev I just confirmed. The files in the command directory are not needed in the root directory. I deleted those files from the root directory and the code still works fine in both Excel desktop and Excel online.

Comment: Thank you for confirming. I've posted that as an answer instead of comments.

Comment: It seems I missed a point in your posts. Everything depends on the webpack configuration .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of trial and error I figured things out. It turns out I was confused about how Office Add-ins worked. Instead of uploading the add-in project, I was supposed to upload the *distribution* of the add-in project. That may be obvious to traditional developers / web developers. But I'm an Excel developer so it's not obvious to me. There's lots of material talking about how to create and run a local add-in. But not many talking about how to upload and distribute such an add-in. So this is what I had to do to make things work:

1. Make your changes to `takepane.js` in the /src/takepane directory in the Office add-in project.
2. Update the `urlProd` constant in the `webpack.config.js` with the URL where the files will be uploaded (I used Github Pages for this)
3. Once you've made and have saved that update, run `npm run build` in the directory for the Office Add-in. This will create the dist directory in your Office add-in folder.
4. Upload the files from the dist directory to the URL you previously assigned to the `urlProd` constant.
5. Upload the `manifest.prod.xml` file from the dist directory (or provide the URL to this file) to the Microsoft 365 admin center.

The route I listed above can be tricky. Using the Azure guide is easier imo. You can look into using that guide [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/publish-add-in-vs-code)

After some delay, the add-in will display. For me the add-in is working in Excel Online. But I'm getting certificate issues with Excel desktop. So I'll be looking into that next.

Comment: This is great feedback for the Office Add-ins Developer docs. I will get this info added. Do you have any suggestions on what would be the best place for this information? What article where you looking at when you encountered this confusion? Thanks.

Comment: @RickKirkham I think a natural place to put this information is perhaps on the See Also section at the bottom on the Build your first Excel task pane add-in tutorial page. So perhaps there should be an extra link that says "Publish Office add-ins". Here's the link I'm referring to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/excel-quickstart-jquery?tabs=yeomangenerator

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the yeoman generator which can be used to scaffold a new add-in project. The newly generated add-in uses `Webpack` as a bundler. In that case it doesn't matter where your files are located.

Comment: By `webpack` are you referring to the `webpack.config.js` file in the root directory? If so, the old yeoman generator I had used this file as well. This has not changed after I've updated yeoman.  Even with the new project with the updated yeoman, my add-in does not work if the taskpane.html file is not located in the root directory. So my problem has not been addressed. I still cannot utilize the javascript code located in the taskpane.js file. It must currently be used in a `<script>` tag in the takepane.html file.

Comment: The location of files depends on the `webpack.config.js` file content.

Comment: Can you provide more detail on what part of the `webpack.config.js` covers this? I see two sections that reference the `takepane.html` file. One is an `Entry` object and the other is a `HtmlWebpackPlugin` object. Each of those objects has the same three properties: `filename`, `template`, and `chunks`.